How can I put condition in Bookly WordPress email notification template (bookly provided documentation is not sufficient)?
I'm trying to modify email notification for Bookly WordPress plugin. Below is given official example:
{#if payment_status}
Here is if block data
{/if}
I want to modify this code on the base of payment_status value. If it is pending or completed. I have tried many ways with no luck. One example is given below which didn't worked as well.
{#if payment_status === 'Pending'}
Here is if block data
{/if}
Thanks,

Is your example based on any available documentation, or just guess work? I can't see https://support.booking-wp-plugin.com/hc/en-us/articles/212411309-Customize-Notifications saying anything about checking actual values, it looks more like this is simply for checking if any value is set, or not.

Yes, I have followed your mentioned documentation. It only shows if a value is set or not. But I want to implement a condition on the base of value.

https://support.booking-wp-plugin.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/14546329572754/comments/14546495375506 suggests that a syntax like {#if service_price != $0.00} should work. Not sure if they have implemented ===, so try just == (or maybe even just =), and the value in that example, although not numeric, is not wrapped into quotes either. So I'd try {#if payment_status == Pending} or something like that.

My bad, I already have tried {#if payment_status == 'Pending'} But didn't tried {#if payment_status == Pending}. It worked. Bundle of thanks for the resolution.

@CBroe this is not working for custom field as custom field names are something like this: custom_field#8290, {#if custom_field#8290 == Yes} is not working.

Thanks to @CBroe for suggestion, and it worked like a charm. Working code is as given below:
{#if payment_status == Pending} Here is if block data {/if}

